# How can I change the ID of a cloned element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a fieldset in a form, and append it at the end of others existing fieldset after renaming the fieldset's legend, and input fields.

Everything is working fine, except the change of the cloned fieldset **id**.

Either I try to change the ID via

```
item.children('fieldset[id^="block_"]:first').attr('id', 'block_'+max_index);
```

or even via

```
item.children('fieldset').attr('id', 'block_'+max_index);
```

The fieldset id remains unchanged ?!

I've done a small piece of code to illustrate the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Levure/4JK5T/

Where is my mistake ?
Many thanks in advance for your tips !

Comment: have you considered using a templating framework?

Comment: @DanielA.White : Thanks for making me discover jQuery templating frameworks, I didn't know these tools ! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, item refers to your fieldset, so the line :

```
item.children('fieldset').attr('id', 'block_'+max_index); // <-- DOES NOT WORK
```

Should become :

```
item.attr('id', 'block_'+max_index); // <-- DOES WORK
```

[Here's the updated (working) fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SG3QR/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.prop`

```
item.prop('id', 'block_'+max_index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't search for children use this

```
    item.prop('id', 'block_'+max_index);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/4JK5T/20/)

Answer (score 0):

first move out max_index from inside event handler to outside and

change this:

```
item.children('fieldset').attr('id', 'block_'+max_index); // <-- DOES NOT WORK
```

to this:

```
item.attr('id', 'block_'+max_index);
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4JK5T/22/